# SSRS moving objects down if the contents of it increase the object in height

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to turn off the fact that objects push down other objects if their height increase?

Example:

I have a text box and then a few inches down I have another text box.

The first text box wasn't big enough length wise so the contents of it generated a second line inside the text box.

This pushed ALL objects below down. I don't want this to happen. I want the text boxes to be FIXED wherever I put them. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set `CanGrow = false` on the textbox. If that doesn't work then you could truncate the value to a max length by using an expression.